# Do I need a driver to use use a Samsung P2770H monitor with macOS?

Tags: macos, display

I am would like to buy a Samsung P2770H monitor to be used with my MacBook Pro. However, when I went to the website of the Samsung, I couldn't find any driver for macOS. I also read on some forum, that Apple doesn't work well with most 3rd party monitors, because Apple is trying to get people to buy their expensive monitors.

While this might be an incentive, I thought the decision to manufacture a driver was up to Samsung and not Apple. But then since I don't know much about this subject, I thought of getting the online expert opinion.

So to be be more precise:

Does anyone know if this particular monitor works with macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X generally doesn't need monitor drivers – it just detects the display's capabilities over the video interface, and lets you choose suitable resolutions & refresh rates in the the Displays preference pane.  I use 3rd party displays with several Macs, and I've never had any trouble.

The thing you do have to worry about is compatibility of the video connection – can you adapt your Mac's video output to the monitor's input?  According to [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/monitors/LS27EFHKUF/ZA-features), the P2770H takes DVI-I or HDMI input; most recentish Macs provide or can be adapted to DVI, so I think you're in pretty good shape there.

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply... I have also read different performance quality depending on the type of connection one uses. I have a mini Display Port (macbook pro 2009), so what would be the best connection/adapter, that i should go for?

Comment: @anagi: The monitor's specs are a little vague, but it looks like is should work with pretty much any Mini-DisplayPort to DVI or HDMI adapter -- its max resolution is only 1920x1080, so you shouldn't need dual-link DVI or anything fancy like that. One thing to watch for is that it probably won't work with DVI-A (analog) adapters & cables.